# Javascript only works in Google Chrome in debug mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, fullscreen, onresize

The code below works fine in Internet Explorer, but in Chrome it only works if you are in debug mode, what's wrong?

```
window.onresize = function (e) {
 if (window.outerWidth === screen.width && window.outerHeight == screen.height) {
    if (!fullscreen) {
        fullscreen = true;
        onfullscreenchange(true);
    }
 } else {
    if (fullscreen) {
        fullscreen = false;
        onfullscreenchange(false);
    }
  }
};


function onfullscreenchange(full) {
    alert(full);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing?

Comment: And, what is it you are trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @pseudosavant Google Chrome does nothing, unless it is in debug mode.

Comment: Did you define `fullscreen` before using it?

Comment: What's "debug mode"?  Do you mean that it only works with the DevTools open?

Comment: @pseudosavant I need to change the layout of a website, upon entering the Fullscreen mode and return to normal when you exit the Fullscreen.

Comment: I'm assuming by fullscreen mode you mean like hitting F11? Will you just be applying different CSS to the page if it is in fullscreen mode.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Debug Mode = F12, Sources and put a pause break in javascript.

Comment: @pseudosavant If onfullscreenchange(true) I call a function if onfullscreenchange(false) I call another. But the chrome seems to ignore everything but shows no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for listening for if the window has been fullscreened with F11. This code listens not just for `resize` events but also for F11 since the `resize` event isn't fired in Chrome when entering fullscreen mode.

```
// Function to check if the window is fullscreened or not
var isFullscreen = function(){
  return (window.outerWidth === screen.width && window.outerHeight === screen.height);
};

// Function to run when window size has changed
var screenSizeChange = function(){
  if (isFullscreen()) {
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = 'You are in fullscreen mode';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = 'You are in windowed mode';
  }
};

// Run screenSizeChange when `resize` event is triggered
window.addEventListener('resize', screenSizeChange, false);

// Run screenSizeChange when F11 is pressed
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 122) { // Listen for F11
    screenSizeChange();
  }
}, false);
```

Live version to try: http://jsbin.com/ciqeb/4/edit?js,output

Comment: Prob. nothing wrong with your code but I think instead of offering just another solution you should guide the OP to fixing his own code

Comment: If you press F11 several times this code is lost and does not perform the correct function.

Comment: Looks like that is actually a bug with Google Chrome. I added some logging and apparently when you enter/exit fullscreen a lot it can stop reporting `window.outerHeight`/`Width` correctly. See here: http://jsbin.com/ciqeb/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var fullscreen;

window.onresize = function (e) { 
 if (window.outerWidth === screen.width && window.outerHeight == screen.height) {
    console.log('fullscreen');
    if (fullscreen !== 1) {
        fullscreen = 1;
        onfullscreenchange(true);
    }
 } else {
    console.log('!fullscreen');
    if (fullscreen !== 0) {
        fullscreen = 0;
        onfullscreenchange(false);
    }
  }
};


function onfullscreenchange(full) {
    alert(full);
}
```

Comment: Does not work in Google Chrome, the code shows no error, Chrome seems to ignore the code.

Comment: This should work fine on any browser. Though, it depends on what you expect it to do. Do you know how to use the developer console?

Comment: If you use this code in Google Chrome and hit F11, the alert is not shown, as in Internet Explorer it works fine.

Comment: That's probably because the resize event doesn't fire when switching to full screen mode. That's why my solution responds to F11 too.

Comment: Would you please create a jsbin/jsfifdle that exhibits the issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Sorry, cannot test "F11" fullscreen mode as i'm on os x (works here). If you manage to fix your code, you should test it on all browsers/OS.